# Где найти класс драйвер сетевой карты в Linux?

Tags: linux, ip, kernel

Подскажите пожалуйста, где именно находится класс-драйвер сетевой карты в ядре Linux, и возможно ли его на ходу переписать?
Конкретно необходимо организовать пересылку всего трафика, который приходит на одну машину на другую машину по известному IP. Сделать это необходимо на как можно более низком уровне (на уровне ядра, на уровне Netfilter). IPTABLES использовать нельзя. Работать в итоге код должен на любом ПК, а значит это не должен быть драйвер для конкретной сетевой карты. Соответственно нужна какая-то прослойка между драйвером устройства и Netfilter.

Comment: iptables не поможет?

Comment: В ядре Linux классов вообще нет (оно на написано на Си).

Comment: iptables к сожалению использовать нельзя.

Comment: @avp, в ядре есть небольшие части на C++(не сильно критичные) и на ассемблере(наиболее узкие в плане производительности места).

Comment: ну, если [*iptables*](http://superuser.com/q/753294/454489) использовать нельзя, то остаётся лишь писать собственный драйвер (модифицировать существующий), либо по статьям [*типа этой*](http://linuxgazette.net/156/jangir.html), либо по книге [*типа этой*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030867.do).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в том то и дело, что необходимо реализовать драйвер так, чтобы он подходил для всех сетевых карт. То есть сделать, что-то выше чем обычный девайс драйвер - класс драйвер.

Comment: насколько мне известно, подобной возможности (с помощью загрузки модуля) в *linux-е* нет. кстати, вот вам ещё [варианты без *iptables*](http://backreference.org/2014/06/17/port-mirroring-with-linux-bridges/) (вообще, несколько странноватое требование. может быть, это [проблема постановки задачи](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/)?)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin попытался описать проблему подробнее.

Comment: @sly_fox4, тогда, вероятно, вам подойдёт *custom netfilter module* (строка для поиска). а реализовать придётся функциональность, аналогичную *iptables tee target* (строка для поиска). только учтите, что модули компилируются под конкретную версию *linux* и под конкретную версию его *config-а*. т.е., например, даже в пределах одной машины, после обновления пакета с *linux-ом* ваш кастомный модуль с большой долей вероятности просто не загрузится.

Comment: ещё из того, что следует учесть: *linux* может быть собран вообще без поддержки модулей либо, например, без поддержки загрузки модулей *netfilter-а*.

Comment: оформил свои комментарии в виде ответа, чтоб вопрос не висел неотвеченным.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov, C++ в ядре Linux? Можно доказательства увидеть?

Comment: @sly_fox4, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю Вам следующие ссылки помогут
[Кодим в ядре Linux`а №6](http://www.hackzona.ru/hz.php?name=News&file=article&sid=2263) - Немного устарело, но [тут](http://lxr.free-electrons.com) можно уточнить.
[LDD3 - Глава 17, Сетевые драйверы](http://dmilvdv.narod.ru/Translate/LDD3/ldd_chapter_17.html) - Пример создания сетевого драйвера, многое разжевано.

PS: Что такое класс драйвера, не понял.

Answer (score 1):

вероятно, вам подойдёт *custom netfilter module* (это строка для поиска, можно найти много руководств и по устаревшим, и по актуальным версиям *linux-а*).

а реализовывать придётся функциональность, аналогичную *iptables tee target* (это строка для поиска, по которй можно найти и справку и примеры использования).

только учтите, что модули компилируются под конкретную версию *linux-а* и под конкретную версию его *config-а*. т.е., например, даже в пределах одной машины и даже без смены дистрибутива, после обновления пакета с *linux-ом* ваш кастомный модуль с большой долей вероятности просто не загрузится.

ещё из того, что следует учесть: *linux* может быть собран вообще без поддержки модулей, либо, возможно (точно сказать не могу, не проверял), без поддержки загрузки модулей *netfilter-а*. но такие ограничения можно встретить скорее лишь у самостоятельно собранных ядер: в популярных не-специализированных дистрибутивах конечно используются загружаемые модули.